# Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments in build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated the gradle version to the 7.0.4 (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4`)

And now in some of my modules I am solving the [problem](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin) with maven.

So i replace `apply plugin: 'maven'` on `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

But I don't understand how to rewrite this section of code correctly:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri("${rootProject.projectDir}/maven-repo"))
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn sourcesJar
```

Because when I start, I get the following error:

> Could not find method uploadArchives() for arguments
> [build_ejkqjjnby5fggiavovparsecy$_run_closure5@c0f0c25] on project
> ':authenticator_sdk' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After I have read the documentation in more detail [here](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin),

I was able to rewrite my problematic code section as follows:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("${rootProject.projectDir}/maven-repo")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I add these lines?

Comment: @JohhanSantana in yours build.gradle(to the bottom).

Comment: repositories.mavenDeployer {
            // Deploy to react-native-event-bridge/maven, ready to publish to npm
            repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven"
            configureReactNativePom pom
        }

Comment: Above is the code how we can modify that and i which line we should do a change. Should we use the 'maven' or 'maven-publish' . Please guide I did't understand

Comment: use 'maven-publish' and replace uploadArchives code with above one helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the error when I am bumping some old gradle project on 6.*.* to 7.4.*. So renaming uploadArchives to publishing helped me. Also I got other error where old code was referring to compile and testCompile but I learned that those need to be chged as
"compile" --> "implementation" and
"testCompile" --> "testImplementation" under dependencies. After these changes my build is successful. I hope this helps.